# Using context outside stateless or stateful widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

Im going to explain my use case for this

I have a inherited widget that has some values like BaseApiUrl and appname

```
class Config extends InheritedWidget {
  Config({
    @required this.appName,
    @required this.flavorName,
    @required this.apiBaseUrl,
    @required Widget child,
  }) : super(child: child);

  final String appName;
  final String flavorName;
  final String apiBaseUrl;

  static Config of(BuildContext context) {
    return context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(Config);
  }

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) => false;
}
```

This works fine inside of context based classes,  but what if i have this class where i need `apiBaseUrl`

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
class LoginRequest {
  Client client = Client();

  Future<Response> login(credentials) async => await client.get('');
}
```

Can be this accomplished ?

Comment: just pass it to constructor

Comment: @alexpfx thats not optimal for me because code duplication would be too much

Comment: you can use a service locator like this one : https://pub.dev/packages/get_it

Answer (score 0):

The context is important so Flutter knows where in the tree to look for the instance of the InheritedWidget, since there could be multiple. If this isn't true for your use case, you could consider moving the required data into a plain singleton class (not a widget).